# FFMPEG latest version for Wamp or Xampp

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I have seen the php ffmpeg project 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-php/files/
the last version was 0.6 in 2008 but I need ffmpeg 1.8 to work on a video sharing script. SO I googled it but came with no results. Anyone know how can I get the php_ffmpeg.dll (for windows i mean) latest version for working with it on my localhost on wamp or xampp?

Comment: You might consider executing FFmpeg directly.  At least in my projects, I've never found the PHP abstraction all that helpful.

Comment: And if you do decide to execute `ffmpeg` directly you can download it at [Zeranoe FFmpeg Builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) (I'm assuming you're using Windows due to mentioning wamp).

Comment: yeah I have already downloaded that but don't really understand how can I configure that with phpvibe 3.6.. ? I am running Xampp 1.8 on a windows 8.1 pc..